# binary formatter to string

Tags: c#

```
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(m, list);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m);
        HiddenField1.Value = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

i'm getting a blank value for HiddenField1.Value. Not sure what I'm doing is even possible? list is definitely populated `(is a List<T>)`

Comment: You mention performance as a concern (comments). If that is the case, are you open to alternate serializers? Protobuf-net is usually less CPU and smaller output. Alexei is entirely correct that you need to encode it though (base-64 is typical, although you can also use higher bases if you write them manually)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve... One option is to show content of the binary stream as Base64 string:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using(memoryStream)
{
    formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, list);
}
HiddenField1.Value = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: all i want to do is move the data from my web form to my .ashx file, would i still need to use .ToBase64String()? I want to pick it up in the form post and re-generate it.

Comment: @rod yes, that is necessary. You **cannot** use a text-reader on arbitrary binary. You must use a base-encode. Base-64 will be more efficient than (say) base-16 (I.e. hex).

Comment: What is the use of `m.Flush();` here ?

Comment: Yes, HTML can't hold arbitrary binary data, so Base64 is convenient way of storing binary in text format. There are other encoding of binary data into text, i.e. you can hex encode (Base16) or UrlEncode - as long as resulting string fits into normal character range (commonly 32-127) you should be ok.

Comment: how do you covert it back from Base64String?

Comment: @L.B, you probably right. Flash may not be needed, but I'm not going to think about it :) - safer to have it than not.

Comment: @Rod `Convert.FromBase64String` gives a `byte[]` - you can `new MemoryStream(byte[])` to get a `Stream`.

Comment: @rod, we build special search engine for those banned on Google :) - http://www.bing.com/search?q=from+Base64String

Comment: sorry, like to hear different perspectives (will get same effect on Google)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov then I guess you are also not going to think about the necessity of `using` with MemoryStream :)

Comment: @L.B reasoning in my head was: something written to a Stream, better call Flush just in case before trying to get underlying data of the stream. And yes, I don't think about necessity of using on MemoryStream - I do it because it is Stream/IDisposable, not because it is actually doing anything...

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    formatter.Serialize(m, list);
    m.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m);
    HiddenField1.Value = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

You need to reset the position of the stream back to the beginning before reading it.  Also, you shouldn't use StreamReader to convert a binary stream like this to text, because it will break in unexpected ways.  If you want the results in a text-like format, use `Convert.ToBase64String` as in @Alexei's answer.

Comment: "missed it by that much!" thanks. hey is a whole lot better to use this way than an xml or json formatters for performance?

Comment: BinaryFormatter is generally much faster, yes.  There are downsides to it, though.  You cannot debug the streams as well, you need to have .NET on both sides of the communication, and you cannot transmit it as text (as you are doing in this example).

Comment: Nononono - you **cannot** use a TextReader on arbitrary binary. This is dangerous and wrong,

Comment: @MarcGravell that's true, but I assumed that is for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Chris even for debugging purposes people usually want the data to be meaningful...